# doubts about database materialization and hashtables

Tags: java, database, hashtable, materialize

I'm a little confused about the concepts of materialization techniques and hashtables.
I'm working on a project and I was told to implement a hashtable in which data is "materialized" (inferred from the origin data with a different structure) and stored in central memory for a later evaluation. This has to be done because the evaluation function is performed very often, and saving part of the information in this hashtable will definitely increase the overall performance.

Now, this evaluation function will be implemented in Java. My question is: can I create this hashtable in Java too and consider the value column as an array of objects, instead of the classic concept of simple key:value structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Arrays in java are objects in and of themselves, you can indeed have an array of objects. The generic binding for the Hashtable would look like this:

```
Hashtable<Object, Object[]> table=new Hashtable<Object, Object[]>();
```

Comment: You can pass the table around like any other object, or make it a global variable if necessary.